# why no index and/or PK on table DATABASECHANGELOG?

Tags: mariadb, liquibase, galera

Quote from [MariaDB Galera Cluster - Known Limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/)

> All tables should have a primary key (multi-column primary keys are
>   supported). DELETE operations are unsupported on tables without a
>   primary key. Also, rows in tables without a primary key may appear in
>   a different order on different nodes.

Galera requires that every table should have a PK, or at least an index. This limation mainly because of replication (wsrep plugin).

We operate a Galera/MariaDB cluster and I see customers with `DATABASECHANGELOG` which has no index and PK. I guess this table is append-only (no update or delete operations)

I don't know Liquibase, that's why I ask for the reason of missing index and/or PK here. Should I open a bug report or do I don't understand this use case?

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| schema                                              | table_rows | non_unique | cardinality | medium distribution | replication row reads |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
(...)
| xxx.DATABASECHANGELOG                               |        571 |       NULL |        NULL |            571.0000 |           326041.0000 |
| xxxx.DATABASECHANGELOG                              |        491 |       NULL |        NULL |            491.0000 |           241081.0000 |
| xxxxx.DATABASECHANGELOG                             |        433 |       NULL |        NULL |            433.0000 |           187489.0000 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [Jira ticket](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1909)

> Liquibase was changed to not create a primary key in databasechangelog table because it introduced problems with key sizes and wasn't really necessary. I didn't put in a check and drop for an existing primary key yet. It should be dropped but doesn't cause a problem unless you are hitting an edge case where you have very long id, author and/or file paths.

There's also described a possible workaround:

> A simple workaround could be to add a change set with a not
>   primaryKeyExists pre-condition and addPrimaryKey change. A more
>   involved workaround could be to create a plugin which overrides the
>   CreateDatabaseChangeLogTableGenerator and/or
>   StandardChangeLogHistoryService which implement PrioritizedService.
>
> Below is an example of the simple workaround. I've optimized the
>   indexes to reduce table scans, sorting and bookmark lookups on SQL
>   Server, but it's probably equally applicable to Oracle. I was not
>   really concerned about the maximum key length of 900 bytes on SQL
>   Server being exceeded.
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
> <databaseChangeLog
>   xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="
>       http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">
>
>   <property name="liquibaseCatalogName" value=""/>
>   <property name="liquibaseSchemaName" value="${database.liquibaseSchemaName}"/>
>   <property name="databaseChangeLogTableName" value="${database.databaseChangeLogTableName}"/>
>   <property name="liquibaseTablespaceName" value=""/>
>
>   <changeSet id="1" author="your-name">
>       <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
>           <primaryKeyExists
>               catalogName="${liquibaseCatalogName}"
>               schemaName="${liquibaseSchemaName}"
>               tableName="${databaseChangeLogTableName}"
>               primaryKeyName="PK_${databaseChangeLogTableName}"/>
>       </preConditions>
>       <dropPrimaryKey
>           catalogName="${liquibaseCatalogName}"
>           schemaName="${liquibaseSchemaName}"
>           tableName="${databaseChangeLogTableName}"
>           constraintName="PK_${databaseChangeLogTableName}"/>
>   </changeSet>
>
>   <changeSet id="2" author="your-name">
>       <createIndex
>           catalogName="${liquibaseCatalogName}"
>           schemaName="${liquibaseSchemaName}"
>           tableName="${databaseChangeLogTableName}"
>           indexName="IX_${databaseChangeLogTableName}_DATEEXECUTED_ORDEREXECUTED"
>           tablespace="${liquibaseTablespaceName}"
>           clustered="true">
>
>           <column name="DATEEXECUTED"/>
>           <column name="ORDEREXECUTED"/>
>       </createIndex>
>   </changeSet>
>
>   <changeSet id="3" author="your-name">
>       <addPrimaryKey
>           catalogName="${liquibaseCatalogName}"
>           schemaName="${liquibaseSchemaName}"
>           tableName="${databaseChangeLogTableName}"
>           constraintName="PK_${databaseChangeLogTableName}"
>           tablespace="${liquibaseTablespaceName}"
>           clustered="false"
>           columnNames="ID,AUTHOR,FILENAME"/>
>   </changeSet>
>
> </databaseChangeLog>
> ```